# Terraform - DynamoDB Table Update without Destroying it

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, terraform, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I already have a resource created (DynamoDB table) using this

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "my_dynamo_table" {   
     name           = "my_table"   
     hash_key       = "Id" 
}
```

Now, I would like to enable streams on this table, if I do this by updating the above resource like this

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "my_dynamo_table" {
  name           = "my_table"
  hash_key       = "Id"
  stream_enable = true
  stream_view_type = "NEW_IMAGE"
}
```

Terraform plans to delete the table and re-create it. Is there any other way, I can just update the table to enable the stream?

Comment: Neither of those things are `ForceNew` attributes so I'm guessing you have another change that is forcing this. Can you share the output of the plan?

Comment: ...and filter the plan down to relevant resources.

Comment: Without knowing I edited some attributes which forces new resources, I guess. I couldn't reproduce it. As you guys mentioned these two attributes does not Force new resources. Thanks for the knowledge.